# Matlab remains busy for no reason while debugging

Tags: matlab, debugging, memory

I am working on 200 images in Matlab...I load the images one at a time, process it, extract features and add it to my data matrix...so when i run the program it takes more than an hour to run...so i added breakpoints to see where the error occurs... i found out that matlab runs fine for the first 50 images...each image gets processed in like 40 seconds. but just one iteration of the 51st image takes forever(i waited for 2 hours still didnt get any output). The data matrix at the 50th image contains 4000*10 entries(the data matrix starts with 0 entries), the other variables are getting continually replaced by newer entries, so that does not add to the memory requirement.(the memory required for the 1st image and 51st image is same ...except for the data matrix) What can be the solution for this problem? why is my program just running forever all of a sudden?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include relevant code? It would be nice to see the loop your are iterating over.

Comment: I figured it out!  Somehow an infinite loop was getting generated.That was causing problems